# How can I run server.js on Python based Google App Engine service

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-platform, angular-universal

My project is Python Google App Engine. and front-end code is written in Angular-Universal. so I want to run server.js for Server Side Rendering on this Project. But I don't know how to run this server.js (node.js express code) on Google App Engine of Python project.

when start this command 'npm run build', server.js and server folder contains server side js are generated, and also browser folder contains front end js are generated.

App.yaml is below.

```
service: my-project
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
- url: /.*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

generated /dist folder after npm run build:dynamic

```
/dist
  |
   ー app.yaml
  |
   ー browser folder
  |      |
  |       ＿ assets folder
  |      |
  |       ー index.html
  |      | 
  |       ー ......
   ー prerender.js
  |
  |
   ー server.js
  |
   ー server folder
        |
         ーassets folder
        |
         ーmain.bundle.js 
        |
         ー .............
```

anyone help please!!

Comment: Unless I'm really missing something, you'll want to deploy 2 apps - one for the Python backend, one for the node front end.

Comment: yes. I want to deploy 2 apps on python gcp application.

Comment: Right.  So you'll want to have separate folders for your code - one for the node code, one for Python.  You'll want to define a separate app.yaml for each.